# Comparison operator problem, when template variable is zero

Tags: php, mysql, zero, comparison-operators

On a content.php page I have the following:

```
$html_videos = '';
if (!empty($videos)) {
    foreach ($videos as $key => $video) {
        $video = PT_GetVideoByID($video, 0, 0, 0);
        $html_videos .= PT_LoadPage('videos/list', array(
            'SELL_VIDEO' => $video->sell_video, 
            'RENT_PRICE' => $video->rent_price 
        ));
    }
}
```

On the list.html page that it loads, I have

```
            <?php $affitta = '{{RENT_PRICE}}'; echo $affitta; if (!empty($affitta) && $affitta !== 0) { ?><span class="bold">|</span> {{LANG rent}} <span style='color:#a84849;font-weight:500;'>$ {{RENT_PRICE}}</span><?php } else { echo "FREE"; } ?>
```

{{LANG rent}} equals to "Rent"

Var $affitta echoes fine all the times; however, be it 0 or 5 it always returns the span, hence "Rent $affitta value" while instead when $affitta equals zero I want it to return "FREE".

I have tried to use && $affitta !== '0' with quotes but same behavior. 
If it may help, column in database is integer and default value is 0. So, what I'm trying to do is to show FREE if RENT_PRICE ($affitta) is zero or rent price if different than zero, but no matter what I try I can never get it to recognize $affitta as zero, although the echo shows that it is zero.

I have extensively searched for an answer and tried various other suggested solution, but with no success.

I hope I have been clear and if not, please, let me know and allow me to clarify. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your life would be easier if, with the last line of code there (in `list.html`), you didn't jump in and out of PHP over and over. This line:

```
<?php $affitta = '{{RENT_PRICE}}'; echo $affitta; if (!empty($affitta) && $affitta !== 0) { ?><span class="bold">|</span> {{LANG rent}} <span style='color:#a84849;font-weight:500;'>$ {{RENT_PRICE}}</span><?php } else { echo "FREE"; } ?>
```

Is simply this:

```
<?php 
$affitta = '{{RENT_PRICE}}'; 
echo $affitta; 
if (!empty($affitta) && $affitta !== 0) { 
    echo '<span class="bold">|</span> {{LANG rent}} <span style="color:#a84849;font-weight:500;">$ {{RENT_PRICE}}</span>';
} else { 
    echo "FREE"; 
}
```

Then, with something more readable, it's very easy to see where your problem lies. You define the value of `$affitta` as `'{{RENT_PRICE}}'`, which obviously doesn't equal 0 or whatever the price may be. Your templating system will substitute `{{RENT_PRICE}}` with the actual value, but here it's not a number. You are in fact evaluating: `if ('{{RENT_PRICE}}' !== 0) {`...

You need to instead compare with the value in `$video->rent_price` earlier up your code. How you access that value depends entirely on what's happening inside your `PT_LoadPage` function.

Comment: Thanks for your directions. Much appreciated. What still confuses me though is when you say that "$affitta as '{{RENT_PRICE}}', obviously doesn't equal 0 or whatever the price may be". I have tried to evaluate as !=='0'. Now, if $affitta echoes '5' as string and I state that if ($affitta !== '0') { do something } since $affitta is '5' and nor '0' why wouldn't it work? In any case, thanks a lot. I'll try to figure out how to compare earlier up on my code.

Comment: '{{WHATEVER}}' doesn't mean anything to PHP. It does not point PHP to the actual value that's substituted with {{WHATEVER}} by your templating system. If you do `echo $affitta; exit;` in your code above, it will not show a value. It will simply show the string '{{RENT_PRICE}}'.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! I'm gonna accept as it definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Cheers. Whether you can handle it inside the  `PT_LoadPage` function (might be tricky, if it's a generic templating engine), or whether you can evaluate earlier and pass the desired HTML into `PT_LoadPage` as another value to substitute in (as you do with the `$video->` values), or whether the templating system allows for some conditional operation by design... good luck getting it sorted, I'm guessing #2 of the above is the easiest to implement.

Comment: I did by using #2, yes. Used conditioning on content.php page like in if ($video->rent_price == '0') { $video->rent_price = "FREE"; then I was able to set 'RENT_PRICE' => $video->rent_price correctly over there and on the template it pulled the correct value. Thanks again for pointing my mistake and make it so that I could fix it.

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for checking in with the results. Good luck moving forward with the project.